# Windows AppSDK, Winui 3 and Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winui-3

Microsoft speeches and videos have said explicitly that Winui 3 and Windows App SDK can be used with any .Net language, including Visual Basic. But I can seem to find no way to actually get started creating one.

There are templates to create a C# or C++ project using Winui 3 in Visual Studio but nothing at all for Visual Basic. I never really got into C based languages, Visual Basic just makes sense to me. I might be able to create a UWP app then follow their instructions to migrate it to Winui 3, but then packaging might become an issue. I have looked everywhere for help on this. Any help (other than learn C#) would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a good question, you can ask it here https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/9361 hurry up it's in a few hours :)

Comment: Oh damn. I'm in Australia so I slept right through this.

Comment: Well, they didn't talk about it (beyond the fact it's *technically* possible), but the issue is not (yet) closed so you may have a chance

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Windows App SDK is full compiled to native code, so any language that can access windows api's should be able to be used. It may be just an issue of there being no preset templates allowing VB with WinUI 3. I know Visual Basic is being edged out, but the VB community is far, far from zero.

Comment: Oh I'm pretty confident it's technicaly possible, but the current C# and C++ templates use some code generation so a vb.net template may not be that easy

Comment: I might just have to hope Microsoft gets over it's anti VB bias and creates a template for it.